# Can not catch boto3 batch_writer exception

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

The following python code is a  batch_write into Dynamodb using boto3:

```
  try:
        chunk_size = 500
        for i in range(0, len(items), chunk_size):
            chunk = items[i:i+chunk_size]
            with table.batch_writer() as batch:
                for item in chunk:
                    dynamodb_item = {
                        'itemId': item['itemId'],
                        'time': item['time'],
                        'value': item['value']
                    }                    
                    batch.put_item( Item = dynamodb_item )     
                                
    except botocore.exceptions.ClientError as error:
        print(error.message)
```

It throws the following exception which is about "exceeding the provisioned throughput", but try-catch does not catch it.
Why it does not catch it?

```
 DEBUG:botocore.parsers:Response body:
b'{"__type":"com.amazonaws.dynamodb.v20120810#ProvisionedThroughputExceededException",
"message":"The level of configured provisioned throughput for the table was exceeded. 
Consider increasing your provisioning level with the UpdateTable API."}'
```

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to catch a `botocore.exceptions.ClientError` while the error being thrown is `ProvisionedThroughputExceededException`. Try changing the type of exception to just `Exception`.